# how to give z-index property in react native android app

Tags: react-native

I searched lot but i did find that how to give z-index property in react native, if i use zIndex in react native it shows me error that this is not valid style prop type.

here is my code in render. as you can see below that i want to make visible to autoContainer view. so please tell me how i can make it front without using any third party library.

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <View style={[styles.inputWrap,this.props.error]}>
       <TextInput
          style={[style.input,this.props.style]}
          ref={this.props.name}
          onChangeText={(text) =>this.searchItem(this.props.options,text)} 
          value={this.state.value}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
          placeholderTextColor="#000000"
          keyboardType={this.props.keyboard}
          />
        </View>
         {this.toggleAuto()}
      </View>
    )
}
 toggleAuto()
  {
    if(this.state.autoList!='')
      {
     return (<View style={style.autoContainer}>
             {this.renderList(this.state.autoList)}
             </View>
       );
      }
  }
const style = StyleSheet.create({
   input:{
    flex:1,
    height:50,
    fontSize:16,
    backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
    paddingLeft:10,
  },
   autoContainer: {
    borderTopColor:"#888888",
    borderTopWidth:1,
    position:"absolute",
    right:0,
    left:0
  },
  list: {
    backgroundColor:'#f2f2f2',
    padding:10,
    borderColor:'#888888',
    borderBottomWidth:1,
    borderLeftWidth:1,
    borderRightWidth:1
  }
});
```

Answer (score 29):

**Updated answer**: `zIndex` now work in ReactNative.

Did you try `elevation` style property?

```
autoContainer: {
    ...,
    elevation: 3,
}
```

Checkout the following links:

1. [View](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html)
2. [Elevation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html#Elevation)

Comment: i tried elevation but , after giving elevation my onPress is not working.

Comment: render that view (which have elevation) bellow all other views

Comment: if i will render that view at the end then its index will be changed like if you have
1. email
2. username
3. firstname
4. lastname
 suppose i want zIndex for firstname , so if i will render it below it gona b problem, please give me a example so i can achieve it. thanks 

Shukarullah Shah

Comment: RN 61.4 zIndex: 999999... doesn't go over elements that have elevation ... I only used the elevation for shadow

Answer (score 0):

Which RN version you are using ?
The current version 0.45 supported zIndex for both Android and iOS
zIndex is supported since version 0.30, checked it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/3d3b067f6fc831b6b23726087fe39cf39ef86f00